# Shields and access/share of power supply for fan

Tags: power-supply, cooling

Deconz Raspbee II, Dresden Electronics shields occupy 10 pins of Raspberry PI, including all 5 V / 3 V. At same time the DIN casings for Raspberry PI do often provide, a fan that needs a power supply itself. [image]How if at all the power supply can be shared and/or provided, yet direct access to those pins is blocked by raspbee II shield?

My Raspberry PI is of version 4B

Comment: Do you have a link to your HAT's product page?

Comment: Here it is: https://phoscon.de/en/raspbee2

Comment: I find it even more current for use cases with DIN rail, where normally a external power supply applies for very much same 5V & GND pins. Now it will be the HAT, fan and power supply competing on those pins.

Answer (score 3):

Here you have images who shows pins who provide power (3.3 and 5 volts).
As the two 5v pins are used by RaspBee2, you still have two 3.3 volts free pins.

> Examples

- Fan red wire = pin 1 or pin 17
- Fan black wire = pin 9 or pin 25

> Working config

I have same configuration (Raspberry 4b + RaspBee2) and I connected a 5v fan on pin 17 and 25. Works like a charm and less noisy than before (without RaspBee and fan red wire on a 5v pin)

[image: Draw of pin use to connect power]

[image: Schema of pin]

Answer (score 2):

If the fan is installed on the SoC (as in your picture), you can just trim the fan wires and solder them to the PCB. GND and 5V pads can easily be located on the back side of the PCB, below the GPIO header.